# Still same error display: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, api, ssl

I am using PHP version 8.1.2 and Laravel version 9.8.1. I fellow these steps from this https://www.scratchcode.io/curl-error-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/ link to resolved this issue. But still I got same error.

[image]

**My code**

`$response = Http::timeout(30)->get('http://example.com/users');`

I also made another project in laravel still I got same error

Comment: You haven't shared any code so far. How should anybody guess how your request is sent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to solve this problem:

- download and extract [cacert.pem](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) following the instructions at https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
- save it on your filesystem somewhere (for example, XAMPP users might use C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem)
- in your php.ini, put this file location in the [curl] section (putting it in the [openssl] section is also a good idea):

Example:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

- restart your webserver (e.g. Apache) and PHP FPM server if applicable

reference [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

You could also remove SSL validation on localhost. Just need to add options to de GuzzleHttp client in the 'withOptions' method to disable verification.

```
 $options = ['verify'=>false];
```

To check if a local environment can do a simple if:

```
public function authApi(){

    $options = [];

    if (App::environment('local')) {
        $options = ['verify'=>false];
    }
    return Http::withBasicAuth($this->client_key, $this->client_key_secret)->withOptions($options);

}
```

Comment: I already try this.

Comment: Try disable the SSL in local. Check the updated answer

Comment: According to your update answer I checked why we used `verify=>false` so purpose of this that its ignore invalid SSL connection errors. I run this below code then its working fine.
`$response = Http::withOptions([
 'debug' => true,
])->get('http://example.com/users');`

Comment: Please guide me why we got this error? where is the main issue when this error comes

Comment: This error occurs because the curl verifies and makes a secure connection request using self-signed certificate. When it does not find the valid certificate, it throws an error.

Comment: You mean that this error is coming from URL which I am using? URL doesn't have self-signed certificate? I am true?

Comment: yes, thats this. if your url have SSL the error disapear.

Comment: I have the problem with Laravel when try to upload file to Cloudflare R2, using Laragon like webserver, Laragon already have that file but when I replace with the file that I download from the answer thats works perfectly, thank you sooo much! after 5 days trying and trying thats work!