# invalid_grant and Invalid JWT Signature

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, service-accounts

Here is my code and the error is at the end.

I'm trying to get the analytics data by country for the ga tracker code

### On Website

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-2YFZD9DYTB"></script>
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'G-2YFZD9DYTB');
</script>
```

#### Code (Updated)

```php
// Set up Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();
// Disable SSL verification for the Guzzle HTTP client
$httpClientConfig = [
    'verify' => false, // This disables SSL verification
];
$httpClient = new Client($httpClientConfig);
$client->setHttpClient($httpClient);
$client->setApplicationName('lookn-387014');
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/account-key.json');
$client->setScopes([
    AnalyticsReporting::ANALYTICS_READONLY
]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
// Analytics Data
$analyticsData = new AnalyticsData($client);
$propertyId = '404314478'; // GA4 property ID
$dateRanges = new DateRange();
$dateRanges->setStartDate(Carbon::now()->subYear()->format('Y-m-d')); // Replace with your desired start date
$dateRanges->setEndDate(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));   // Replace with your desired end date
// Metric
$metric = new Metric();
$metric->setExpression('metrics/sessions'); // Replace with your desired metric
// Dimension
$dimension = new Dimension();
$dimension->setName('ga:country');
// Request
$request = new RunReportRequest();
$request->setProperty('property', 'properties/' . $propertyId);
$request->setDateRanges([$dateRanges]);
$request->setDimensions([$dimension]); // Set dimensions
$request->setMetrics([$metric]);

$response = $analyticsData->properties->runReport($propertyId, $request);
```

#### Error

```json
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
```

#### Service Account Keys

My keys are brand new and active

[image]

#### More information

Under: **Property access management** my service account has "Administrator" Standard Role selected

#### Granted Roles

[image]

#### Creds file

[image]

Comment: it seems that you are reading Universal analytics which has been expired some months ago, you need to move to GA4 https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13486733?hl=en

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I seem to be using the GA4 as this was a newly created analytics account which was created about 1 month ago

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I followed your link and watched that video, it didn't apply to me as i dont have any ua- accounts/properties

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I also followed this [guide](https://www.monsterinsights.com/beginners-guide-to-user-permissions-in-google-analytics/) (the first part) and now I'm where I'm at

Comment: @ShilaMosammami My service account has the "Administrator"  Google Analytics Permission

Comment: I see in your code you are setting viewId $request->setViewId('404314478'); which does not exist anymore in GA4. Do you have property Id or measurement Id?

Comment: @ShilaMosammami 404314478 is the property id, is there another php api i need to use instead of the one in my post?

Comment: So the code you have written does not belong to GA4, but instead belongs to UA which is already expired. I try to find your answer and write it as the response

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I've updated my code but I get the same issue

Comment: when did you set up your Gtag codes at the front-end side? has it passed 48 hours?

Comment: Never disables SSL verification. Correctly configure PHP which is very easy. I wrote some tips about this: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/curl-ssl-certificate-problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you should use is called `Google Analytics Data API (GA4)`

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */
$property_id = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'city',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);

// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Source :[GA Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#php)

Comment: Thanks, but getting error `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` how to solve?

Comment: This error is common when trying to communicate with external APIs,  via cURL in a PHP environment. It's because the cURL client needs to have access to a set of trusted public certificates (CA root certificates) to verify the server's SSL certificate.

Comment: use the accepted response in this like please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71909552/still-same-error-display-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get

Comment: I get the error `Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials`

Comment: Are you able to read the info of your GA4?

Comment: i cant connect, i need to include the oauth client id and secret, just not sure where to set them

Comment: use this link for the credentials https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4#php

Comment: anyway, I hope you have the credentials.json file

Comment: Now I get `Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential` see my question for the account-key.json

Comment: do you have your account-key.json file?

Comment: yes I do, `__DIR__ . '/account-key.json` that the location, next to my script

Comment: i've even tried `putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/account-key.json');`

Comment: is that a physical file available in the pass :   . __DIR__ . '/account-key.json and can you share the json hiding important info

Comment: yes its available, i shared in my question, not posting the whole json lol

Comment: That was enough for me to see that there is "type": "service_account" and the provided Email, now please check if this email on analytics.google account has given the access. exactly the email inside the json file

Comment: from the errors i've gotten for the new property, is that i need to get an access token and a refreash token, by redirecting and signing into google

Comment: i don't think so, at least I do not need to go through refreshing stuff. did you check if the exact email inside the json has the administrator access in analytics.google ?

Comment: yes the service account has access

Comment: i found a solution, just add this to your code solution, `$jsonFile = __DIR__ . '/account-key.json';
        $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient( [
            'credentials' => json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonFile), true)
        ]);`